# MAUI CarouselView DataTemplate databinding

Tags: maui

I am trying to build a custom TabView control in .net MAUI using a ContentView and I'm running into some issues with databinding. The basic idea is to have tabs at the top of the control and then use a carouselview below to show the individual pages / contentviews.

Each TabViewItem looks like this:

```
public class TabViewContentItem : BindableObject
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Content", typeof(View), typeof(TabViewContentItem));
    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Header", typeof(string), typeof(TabViewContentItem));
    public View Content
    {
        get
        {
            return (View)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the TabView set up like this so that the content property is set to a collection of TabViewItems

```
[ContentProperty("ContentItems")]
public partial class TabView : ContentView
{
    private ICommand _itemSelected;

    public TabView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentItems = new ObservableCollection<TabViewContentItem>();            
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TabViewContentItem> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<TabViewContentItem> ContentItems
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it in the xaml like so:

```
<controls:TabView x:Name="MyTabView">
    <controls:TabView.ContentItems>
        <controls:TabViewContentItem Content="{controls:ItemExample BindingContext={Binding Item1ViewModel}}" Header="Item 1" />
        <controls:TabViewContentItem Content="{controls:ItemExample2 BindingContext={Binding Item2ViewModel}}" Header="Item 2" />
    </controls:TabView.ContentItems>
</controls:TabView>
```

I then create a carousel and add it to the control's content.

```
    MyCarousel = new CarouselView
    {
        Loop = false
    };

    MyCarousel.ItemsSource = ContentItems;
    MyCarousel.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        var view = new ContentView();
        view.SetBinding(ContentProperty, "Content");
        return view;
    });
```

This is working in that the content views are being displayed in the Carousel, but the binding context is not being bound correctly to the child views (I assume because the carousel's binding context is the TabView page)

[image]

If I forget the idea of using a carousel, and just use a stack layout to show individual pages as necessary, the binding context is preserved / set on the individual pages and everything displays correctly.

```
MyStackLayout.Children.Add(ContentItems.First().Content);
```

[image]

How can I set the binding context of the views in the DataTemplate for the CarouselView? I am trying using relative / ancestor binding but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post code as text only, this includes XAML.

Comment: @ewerspej Replaced image with XAML code

Comment: What if you set the binding source for the custom Tabview in the CarouselView like [this one](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13669#issuecomment-773918838)? If it's not working, please help  create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via Github link.